# How Do I Prevent Users from Going to Previous/Next Page While They are Scrolling Left/Right inside a scrollable div?

Tags: html, css, browser, user-experience

I'm having this fairly minor but very irritating UX issue.

One of the pages requires a really wide table, which I've put inside a scrollable div.

The issue that I'm having is that when the user scrolls left or right using the trackpad on a mac, they will often accidentally trigger the "go to next/last page" behavior in Chrome if they keep trying to scroll right/left after they have already gotten all the way to the edge of the table.

Is there some way to disable the two-finger go forward/back trackpad behavior while they are hovering over a specific div?

```
CSS:

.scrollable {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

HTML:
 <div class="scrollable" id="tableHere">
   <table>
      -- a really wide table --
   </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer no you can not do it, what you could do is put scrolling div in loop like if user scrolls to end of the div and scrolls again move the scroll to start again

Comment: How do I do that? Is it a CSS thing?

Comment: I am not sure about css but it could be implemented with js